# how to return JSON object if search string matches with any value Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this kind of object

```
[
 {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:00 AM",
   recipients: "junaid@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 10:59"
 },
 {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
   recipients: "musaa@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 11:05"
  }
]
```

I am trying to do a search filter on this object in Vue, this object is designed as `data: []` in the data part of Vue component.

What I am trying to do is to change the value of this.data on basis of the search query. For example, if my search string is `jun` then I only get one object which contains `jun`, I want to check this search string to each object's key and value.

I have tried this.

```
onFilterSet (filters) {
  const oldData = this.data
  let search = filters.search
  if (search != null || search != "") {
    this.data = this.data.filter((item) => {
      return _.includes(item.recipients, search) || _.includes(item.camera_ids, search) || _.includes(item.camera_ids_failed, search) || _.includes(item.subject, search);
    });
  } else {
    this.data = oldData
  }
},
```

But this is not working. `this.data` value is not getting changed also not coming back to the old state when the search query is again empty. Please guide me.

UPDATE:

I am searching for anything, an example is: search string is: `jun`, I want to check it against camera_ids, camera_ids_failed, recipients, subject, if any of those key's values match `jun`, it should filter object and return it.

If the first object looks like this

```
[
 {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:00 AM",
   recipients: "junaid@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 10:59"
 },
 {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
   recipients: "musaa@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 11:05"
  },
  {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
   recipients: "hibaa@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled Junaid @ 11:05"
  },
  {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
   recipients: "hajraa@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 11:05"
  }
]
```

and search value is `jun`

The updated object after filter will be

```
[
 {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:00 AM",
   recipients: "junaid@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 10:59"
 },
  {
   camera_ids: "all",
   camera_ids_failed: "failed",
   inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
   recipients: "hibaa@evercam.io",
   subject: "Your Scheduled Junaid @ 11:05"
  }
]
```

Comment: which value you are searching for in the json

Comment: I think i have made it very clear and now I have updated it again

Comment: Any value User can add. its just object's key's any value if it matches,  any key's value matches it should be in next updated object

Comment: Are you sure you want to match against the keys? Eg, if I typed _"camera"_, all results should be returned?

Comment: Key's Value. not keys

Comment: I have again updated with an example.

Comment: _"Key's Value. not keys"_  otherwise known as just _"values"_ ;)

Comment: @Phil "..formerly known as values" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{
    camera_ids: "all",
    camera_ids_failed: "failed",
    inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:00 AM",
    recipients: "junaid@evercam.io",
    subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 10:59"
  },
  {
    camera_ids: "all",
    camera_ids_failed: "failed",
    inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
    recipients: "musaa@evercam.io",
    subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 11:05"
  }
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      data,
      filtered: data,
      term: ''
    }
  },

  watch: {
    term(val) {
      this.filtered = this.data.filter(d => {
        for (let name in d) {
          if (d[name].toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            return d;
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="term" />

  <pre>{{ filtered }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: it also fails sometimes if the value is an integer. :)

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Then convert everything to string first before comparing, like, `(d[name] + '').toLowerCase().indexOf(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use the `reduce` function and in its call back use `for..in` to iterate the object. Then use includes to check if the key's value contain the string, then push this object to the accumulator array.

This demo does not include case, so modify it according to case sensitivity.

```js
let data = [{
    camera_ids: "all",
    camera_ids_failed: "failed",
    inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:00 AM",
    recipients: "junaid@evercam.io",
    subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 10:59 ,Test for jun"
  },
  {
    camera_ids: "all",
    camera_ids_failed: "failed",
    inserted_at: "Monday, 25 Feb 2019 6:06 AM",
    recipients: "musaa@evercam.io",
    subject: "Your Scheduled SnapMail @ 11:05"
  }
]

function findObj(str) {

  return data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    for (let keys in curr) {
      if (curr[keys].includes(str)) {
        acc.push(curr)

      }

    }
    return acc;
  }, [])

}

console.log(findObj('jun'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite `data` with new values, you lose anything that is filtered out.

What you want is a computed property representing the *filtered* set of data. This will only compute if the `data` or `search` values change which makes it very efficient.

For example

```js
data () {
  return {
    search: '',
    data: [/* your array here */]
  }
},
computed: {
  filtered () {
    if (!this.search) {
      // empty search, return all values
      return this.data
    }
    let normalizedSearch = this.search.toLowerCase()
    return this.data.filter(datum => Object.values(datum).some(val => 
            String(val).toLowerCase().includes(normalizedSearch)))
  }
}
```

Then in your template

```html
<input v-model="search">
<div v-for="item in filtered">
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```